The value passed to the ejs template is not getting displayed
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Checkout</h1>

    <h2>Your Cart</h2>
    <div id="cartItemsContainer">
      <% locals.userForCheckout.forEach(cartItem => { 
        console.log(cartItem+"-----");
        %>
        
        <div class="cart-item">
            <p>Quantity:<%= cartItem.quantity %></p>
           <p><strong><%= cartItem.item.name %></strong></p>
           <p>Price: <%= cartItem.item.price %> Rs</p>
        </div>
      <% }) %>
  </div>

And This is the actual object structure of usersForCheckOut
{
  item: {
     _id: new ObjectId('66eec46afb9000e3419b97cd'),
    name: 'Chicken Biryani',
    category: 'Indian',
    stock: 20,
    price: 12.5
  },
  quantity: 1,
  _id: new ObjectId('66eed1b805bd6cceb0d9d0c2')
}

Here cartItem.quantity is getting displayed but cartItem.item.name is throwing an error.
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

can you remove the <p><strong><%= cartItem.item.name %></strong></p>  and <p>Price: <%= cartItem.item.price %> Rs</p> if the error still there. if not then maybe some records dont have the item field

Based on what you say, that isn't the structure of usersForCheckOut but of one cartItem.  So the structure of usersForCheckOut is more like [{quantity: 1, _id: new ObjectId('66eed1b805bd6cceb0d9d0c2'), item: {...}}, {...}]

Also you mention that but cartItem.item.name is throwing an error, but never say what error you are encountering.
